# MySQL default values not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, insert, default-value

**Hi friends from SO!**

This code used to be working, but it seems like it stop working when I cloned the database. There's a table called maps, which has some default values, like maximum. As far as I understand, if my INSERT code has no value, then, the dafault value will be used.

This is what I'm doing:

**These values might be there, as they might not be there.**

```
$scan->maximo_exploracion   = addslashes($_GET['scan_maximo_exploracion']);
$scan->proceso_analisis = addslashes($_GET['scan_proceso_analisis']);
$scan->email_user           = addslashes($_GET['scan_email_user']);
$scan->email_owner          = addslashes($_GET['scan_email_owner']);
```

**Then:**

```
db_ask($db_resonance_slave, "
INSERT INTO mapas
SET
usuario_id              = '$user->id',
maximo_exploracion      = '$scan->maximo_exploracion',
proceso_analisis        = '$scan->proceso_analisis',
email_user              = '$scan->email_user',
email_owner             = '$scan->email_owner',
max_proc                = '5',
proceso_exploracion     = 'esperando',
direccion               = '$scan->address',
dominio                 = '$scan->dominio',
dominio_id              = '$dominio->id',
server_address          = '$scan->server_address',
server_zone             = '$scan->zone_name',
server_zone_code        = '$scan->zone_code',
server_response_speed   = '$scan->server_response_speed'
");
```

Now, a few days ago, with the same code, if **$scan->maximo_exploracion**  didn't have any information, the record would be inserted with the default value which is 100.

At this moment, it's appearing blank. Which, of course, is causing problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Chris;

---

**The Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `mapas` (
`id` INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`usuario_id` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`maximo_exploracion` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
`max_proc` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`open_proc` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`hora_lanzado` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`dominio` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`dominio_id` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`idioma` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`server_address` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`server_zone` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`server_zone_code` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`server_response_speed` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`proceso_exploracion` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'esperando',
`proceso_analisis` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'esperando',
`email_owner` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'False',
`email_user` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'True',
`eliminado` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`creacion` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

COMMENT='Almacena mapas, los mapas son ordenes de exploración y análisis para un dominio específico.'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: If all you changed was on DB side, why not post all information regarding the DB side?

Comment: Mr / Miss fancyPants, that's absolutely logical, and it's what I've done just now.

Comment: And this is from the cloned database or the original one? Just to be sure...

Comment: As I wasn't expecting this, I removed the original one. This is from the cloned database. This is a fragment of a web crawler, as it was getting too big, I divided the database, creating a master / slave scheme. However, now is doing this behavior...

Comment: @fancyPants also, it might be important to know that I cloned the database using a function for that in Plesk. Besides that, the table structure, looks just fine to me. I know I could do a workaround in PHP, but it's not the idea...

Comment: My suspicion is that your script is setting maximo_exploracion to blank rather than NULL. As blank is not null it isn't inserting the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps: 
http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/mysql-quirk-not-null-defaults

It indicates using an extended insert (where you specify multiple rows in an insert statement), that you can bypass this default value; a warning is provided instead of errros.  Yet single insert statements throw an error.

This can be avoided presently by

```
Set sql_mode = "strict_all_tables";
```

Then use the the default keyword, which will insert that column’s default value.

Comment: According to post on 2ndary question... this didn't resolve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491008/not-null-default-being-100-ignored?noredirect=1#comment37913926_24491008

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you're passing a blank instead of NULL. Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['scan_maximo_exploracion']) && $_GET['scan_maximo_exploracion']) {
    $scan->maximo_exploracion   = addslashes($_GET['scan_maximo_exploracion']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Oli, I'm not sure, but since the $_GET['scan_maximo_exploracion'] is not assigned at all, the representation $scan->maximo_exploracion should be null, not empty.

Comment: I would like to preserve the PHP as it is, since I know it's functional... or well, it used to be. However, an approach like yours could be -- if ($scan->maximo_exploracion == '') { unset($scan->maximo_exploracion); }

Comment: addslashes() will return a string, regardless of the contents of $_GET right now.

Comment: Addslashes() removed - (kids: on development environment just for testing proposes) and it's still behaving the same, the variable is 100% clear, and the MySQL doesn't behaves as expected.

Comment: What happens when you remove "maximo_exploracion = '$scan->maximo_exploracion'," from the db_ask() ?

Comment: You're clever man, would like to work with you! I did that, right after trying to remove the addslashes, and yes, it works, which proves that the default value on the MySQL works, however, it's somehow storing empty, instead.

Comment: Still, I'm 100% sure that there's something to be done on the MySQL, as it was working and I've been coding this way for quite a long time (I prefer to avoid unnecessary lines - "less is more"). I found a few differences in the COLLATE structure of the cloned database, and I found different behaviors, depending the Encoding... Seriously, mysql can be painful.