# Why aren't MySql default values updating?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a site using ByetHost. I updated the a couple of MySql char columns' default values using the Admin tools, as shown here: [Imgur Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUR0w.jpg)

When I look at the structure of the database, it shows the correct default values: [Imgur Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9if.jpg)

However, the actual columns do not update: [Imgur Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLjiS.jpg)
(I have not made any entries in this column so it should only contain the default, which used to be "Easy.")

I'm certain that when I used this exact procedure in the past, it automatically updated the default values in the database's columns. Is this a temporary issue on Byethost's end or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: so, you want to update all AddingFractionsLevel value to medium ? then just do UPDATE table_name SET AddingFractionsLevel = 'Medium', The default value will fill the column if you not set the value when you do insert

Comment: @BaimWrong Nope, I just want the default to be "Medium." Previously, I used this method to set the default to "Easy." Because there weren't any entries in that column, every entry in the column changed to "Easy." Now, I changed the default to "Medium" and it still says "Easy."

Comment: have you try insert new record with AddingFractionsLevel value not set / empty after change the default value ?

Comment: @BaimWrong Yes and nothing happens. Do you think this is a temporary issue on Byethost's end?

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488826/mysql-default-values-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Does the default value show in the Insert tab? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?